# Is storing temporary files into JackRabbit a good idea?

Tags: java, temporary-files, jackrabbit, jcr

does anobody know how much overhead jackrabbit has, in comparison with pure FS persistence ?

I'm using it for a CMS project, but I also have to persist temporary files (**that unfortunately have properies/metadata**)... Don't know if I should also employ jackrabbit for that.

I think the overhead is significant enough to avoid this .... at least the IO on filesystem.

These files are the same as the rest of files in repo, but it is for sure, that they will be deleted in a minute.

Should I create a layer to persist files with properties via JAVA IO API, should I use jackrabbit or should I use database ? If so, can it be set for performance somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Jackrabbit stores the binaries in the [`FileDataStore`](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore), which uses a `FileOutputStream`, so the overhead is relatively low. However, the binaries in the data store remains until garbage collected, which might be a problem for you if you create a huge number of temporary files.

Metadata: it depends how much metadata you have. The metadata is stored in the persistence manager and possibly in the search index (Lucene). The main performance problem there is usually fulltext search, so disable it if possible.

> should I use jackrabbit or should I use database

That really depends on your use case. Jackrabbit does not claim to be "faster than a database", but the data model (hierarchical, key value pairs) may be better or easier to use.